# Assigning multiple column values in a single row of pandas DataFrame, in one line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to Assign multiple values to a single row in a DataFrame and I need the correct syntax.

See the code below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'A': range(10),
'B' : '',
'C' : 0.0,
'D' : 0.0,
'E': 0.0,
})

#Works fine
df['A'][2] = 'tst'

#Is there a way to assign multiple values in a single line and if so what is the correct syntax
df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']][3] = ['V1', 4.3, 2.2, 2.2, 20.2]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Strictly you mean *"Assign vector of values to multiple columns in a single row of DataFrame"*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) (and avoid chaining):

```
In [11]: df.loc[3] = ['V1', 4.3, 2.2, 2.2, 20.2]
```

*This ensures the assigning is done inplace on the DataFrame, rather than on a copy (and garbage collected).*

You can specify only certain columns:

```
 In [12]: df.loc[3, list('ABCDE')] = ['V1', 4.3, 2.2, 2.2, 20.2]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you I knew there was a way to do it.

Comment: What if i want to assign multiple new columns?

Comment: @V3ss0n You can do something like `df.loc[[3, 4], list('ABCDE')] = ...` (a list inside).

Comment: @AndyHayden I can't add multiple columns with more than 1 row of data, only 1 column. I just tried to run df.loc[[3,4], list('ABCDE')] as suggested above on an indexed no-column dataframe: pandas seems to expect the new columns to exist already (Error is no ['A','B',...] not in index)... ie adding multiple columns (ie a dataframe) into an existing dataframe (without columns) for specific rows doesn't seem to work for me? `code` `a = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3,4,5])
a.loc[[3,4], list('ab')] = pd.DataFrame(index=[3,4], data=[['abc', 'xyz'], ['123', '789']])`

Comment: @smci yes it is! Use loc for labels (like in this question), iloc for position.

Comment: I mean I know .loc still exists, I'm asking you if there is still a major performance advantage to using it in 0.19? Any idea how much?

Comment: @smci compared to what? This may make an interesting separate question. Generally the reason you like to avoid chaining, is partially for perf, is mainly due to sometimes loc returns a copy rather than a view which if you update doesn't update the original. Pandas does it's best to warn you about this, and it has got better about it, but it's still best practice to not chain your locs.