# How to set multiple values of Pandas dataframe where condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to set multiple values of pandas dataframe columns where a condition, but I got an error message:

```
df[df['store_id'] == 'UK00023', ['sale','startdate','enddate']] = [100, str(datetime.now()), str(datetime.now())]

But I got this error:
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of '
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: Related: [Assigning multiple column values to a python pandas DataFrame in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882501/assigning-multiple-column-values-to-a-python-pandas-dataframe-in-one-line)

Comment: Use `.loc` accessor for selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.ix[df['store_id'] == 'UK00023', ['sale','startdate','enddate']] = [100, str(datetime.now()), str(datetime.now())]
```